# How to make each parameter appear in a table row?

Tags: thingsboard

I have a device that get some telemetry data via REST API. Some of the data that it received is in the following format:

```
{
    ...
    parameters: [
        {
            'name': 'parameter1',
            'grade': '2',
            'info': 'some informtion'
        },
        {
            'name': 'parameter2',
            'grade': '1',
            'info': 'some informtion'
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

what I want to do is to visualize the data in the following way:

```
     name    | grade | info
---------------------------------------
 parameter1  |   2   | some information
 parameter2  |   1   | some information
    ...      |  ...  |       ...
```

now if I break down each parameter and send it to the device separately it will override the previous one.
How can I make that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out a way to do this:

1. Go to 'Widget Bundle' and create a new widget bundle.
2. Create a new widget of type 'Latest values'.
3. Here we have CSS/HTML section and a Javascript section.

HTML section:

```
<div class="my-data-table">
</div>
```

Javascript section:

```
self.defaultList = [
    {
        'id': 1,
        'name': 'name 1', 
        'grade': 123, 
        'description': 'This is a description'
    },
    {
        'id': 2,
        'name': 'name 2', 
        'grade': 456, 
        'description': 'More description'
    }, 
    {
        'id': 3,
        'name': 'name 3', 
        'grade': 789, 
        'description': 'Even more description'
    }
];

self.createTable = function(data) {
    const columnNames = Object.keys(data[0]);
    let tableHeadContent = $('<tr></tr>');
    columnNames.forEach((columName) => {
        tableHeadContent.append('<td>' + columName + '</td>');
    });
    let tableHead = $('<thead></thead>').append(tableHeadContent);
    let tableBody = $('<tbody></tbody>');
    
    data.forEach((currentElement, index) => {
        const vals = Object.values(currentElement);
        let currentRow = $('<tr></tr>');
        vals.forEach((val) => {
           currentRow.append('<td>' + val + '</td>');
        });
        tableBody.append(currentRow);
    });
    return $('<table></table>').append(tableHead).append(tableBody);
}

self.onInit = function() {
    let currentList = [...self.defaultList];
    if(self.ctx.defaultSubscription.data[0].data.length !== 0) {
        currentList = JSON.parse(self.ctx.defaultSubscription.data[0].data[0][1]);
    }
    let currentTable = self.createTable(currentList);
    $('.my-data-table', self.ctx.$container).append(currentTable);
}

self.onDataUpdated = function() {
        self.ctx.detectChanges();
}
```

What you need to pay attention to and understand is `self.ctx.defaultSubscription.data`, when you visualize your data with a certain widget you subscribe the data to the widget. `self.ctx.defaultSubscription.data` give you access to the data, you can `console.log()` it to see how it is structured.

The `self.defaultList` is for the preview and when you set this widget to a specific data it will use that data.

There may be other way to do this but this is how I did it.